# Unable to add ES2021 in compiler target - Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have the below `tsconfig.json` where I am unable to use ES2021 version for compiler target.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

Whenever I use ES2021, I get an error:

> tsconfig.json:3:15 - error TS6046: Argument for '--target' option must be: 'es3', 'es5', 'es6', 'es2015', 'es2016', 'es2017', 'es2018', 'es2019', 'es2020', 'esnext'.

I have tried adding like:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2021",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": [ "ES2021" ]
  }
}
```

But still no luck. I had initially tried using `es2021` then later moved to `ES2021` upon browsing a few sites.

And went through a couple of chains [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41238) and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45063) where one issue is still open and other suggests for a TSC version above 4.3.5 to fix this. Whereas mine stands at 4.6.2

I would need the `replaceAll` logic from ES2021. That's the reason I am looking this out for. Am I missing something here? Do we have a fix for this?

**Versions**:

- VS Code - 1.65.2
- Node.js - 14.16.0
- Typescript - 4.6.2

**Error image**:

[image: Error]

**Error trace**:

```
tsconfig.json:3:15 - error TS6046: Argument for '--target' option must be: 'es3', 'es5', 'es6', 'es2015', 'es2016', 'es2017', 'es2018', 'es2019', 'es2020', 'esnext'.

3     "target": "ES2021",
                ~~~~~~~~

tsconfig.json:10:14 - error TS6046: Argument for '--lib' option must be: 'es5', 'es6', 'es2015', 'es7', 'es2016', 'es2017', 'es2018', 'es2019', 'es2020', 'esnext', 'dom', 'dom.iterable', 'webworker', 'webworker.importscripts', 'scripthost', 'es2015.core', 'es2015.collection', 'es2015.generator', 'es2015.iterable', 'es2015.promise', 'es2015.proxy', 'es2015.reflect', 'es2015.symbol', 'es2015.symbol.wellknown', 'es2016.array.include', 'es2017.object', 'es2017.sharedmemory', 'es2017.string', 'es2017.intl', 'es2017.typedarrays', 'es2018.asyncgenerator', 'es2018.asynciterable', 'es2018.intl', 'es2018.promise', 'es2018.regexp', 'es2019.array', 'es2019.object', 'es2019.string', 'es2019.symbol', 'es2020.bigint', 'es2020.promise', 'es2020.string', 'es2020.symbol.wellknown', 'esnext.array', 'esnext.symbol', 'esnext.asynciterable', 'esnext.intl', 'esnext.bigint', 'esnext.string', 'esnext.promise'.

10     "lib": [ "ES2021" ]
                ~~~~~~~~


Found 2 errors.
```

Comment: What if you update your TypeScript version to latest? In the playground using v4.6+ there is an option for ES2021

Comment: Let me check that kellys.

Comment: Didn't work Kellys. I had the image and trace updated in the question.

Comment: What command are you running that is printing those error?

Comment: I am using the 'Run->Start Debugging' from VS Code which is when I get that error.

Comment: Why is this happening? Any resolution?

Answer (score 5):

I guess this answer comes too late but to anyone who comes around :

The reason is that Node 14.16.0 does not support ES2021. As you can see here  https://node.green/#ES2021 , ES2021 support begins with Node 15.14. If you want to use ES2021, you will need to use Node 15 (or actually Node 16, due to how Node versions work) or later. :)

Comment: I've updated to Node 19.0.0 and still get this error while using ES2021.

Comment: @aaron9eee Then maybe it comes from your Typescript version, which one are you using ? I don't know what version introduced es2021 support but I know es2022 came in TS4.5, so maybe you should target a version aroud this one.

By the way you should always pair versions of Node.js (16, 18, 20..) because odd versions are unstable, it may also cause your problem :)